# TableView: get value of textField in HeaderCell

Tags: swift

how can I get the value of a header Cell of an UITableView?
With the following code I get the values of a cell within a section. But how can I change this that it will work with header cells?

```
      let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: h)
      tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)

      let currentCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TeamInput", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TeamInputTableViewCell
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a headerView in a `UITableView` you can do it like this:

```
let headerView = tableView.headerViewForSection(indexPath.section)
```

By the way if you want to access an existing cell in your table view you should not use `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier`, because that method returns a new cell from the queue and not one that is currently displayed. To access one of the displayed cell you should use:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```